# External JS function not found in html file without error message. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I try to call an external javascript function in my html file. It doesn't work and there isn't any error message. Whats wrong?

Here is the external javascript function code:

```
function startNewGame() {
    setState(WAITING);
    level = 1;
    user.reset();
    map.reset();
    map.draw(ctx);
    startLevel();
}
```

And here the codes in the html file:

```
<div id="pacman">
      <a id="startbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="">Start new game</a>
      <script src="/pacman/pacman.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/pacman/modernizr-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </div>
```

Javascriptcode in html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var game = document.getElementById("pacman");

    if (Modernizr.canvas && Modernizr.localstorage && 
        Modernizr.audio && (Modernizr.audio.ogg || Modernizr.audio.mp3)) {
      window.setTimeout(function () { PACMAN.init(game, "<?php echo $root; ?>"); }, 0);

    } else { 
      game.innerHTML = "Sorry, needs a decent browser<br /><small>" + 
        "(firefox 3.6+, Chrome 4+, Opera 10+ and Safari 4+)</small>";
    }

    document.getElementById("startbutton").onclick = function()
        {
         PACMAN.startNewGame
        }
</script>
```

I want that the Pacman Game will start by clicking the "startbutton". It doesn't work. The startNewGame function in the external JS-file is a sub function from the function

```
var PACMAN = (function () {
/*here are many other functions - also the startNewGame function*/
return {
        "init" : init
       };
}());
```

Maybe the indication to call the startNewGame function is wrong but i don't know how to indicate it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Is the `startNewGame` function even exported in the return object? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: No it wasn't. Now i have exported the `startNewGame` function in the return object and chrome inspector display error messages. Thank you for the tip so now finally i can go forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> PACMAN.startNewGame
> ```

Just mentioning a property name won't do anything. You have to say what you want to do with it.

To call a function, append `()`.

Comment: i mentioned also the property name in the code above:

 `window.setTimeout(function () { PACMAN.init(game, "<?php echo $root; ?>"); }, 0);`

init is a function from the `var PACMAN = (function () {...` in the external JS File. 

The function `startNewGame()` is also a function from the `var PACMAN = (function () {...` which said inside what is to do. 

Why it works with `PACMAN.init` and doesn't works with `PACMAN. startNewGame`?